# Send message to MQQueue from Listener onmessage

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I have this particular scenario where:

- MQSender (sends "Hello" text message to the test queue in IBMMQ)
- MQSenderInternal (sends "Loop" text message to the test queue in
  IBMMQ)
- MQListener (receives the message if it's Hello then will send another
  message with MQSenderInternal)

MQSender runs as a standalone Java Application while MQSenderInternal & MQListener are part of the same jar and deployed in a JBoss server.

The flow goes like this --> MQSender --> MQListener --> MQSenderInternal --> MQListener (since the message is Loop it should stop)

Thing is that when MQListener calls MQSenderInternal to send the message to the queue it listens, it throws an exception (JMSCC0109:A message driven bean threw a runtime exception) and it enters into a redelivery infinite loop.

I'd like to be able to send messages to the test queue from inside the onmessage method that listens to it without throwing any exceptions... is this possible?

Snippets:

MQSender

```
MQQueueConnectionFactory cf = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
cf.setHostName(host);
cf.setPort(port);
cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
cf.setQueueManager(manager);
cf.setChannel(channel);

MQQueueConnection connection = (MQQueueConnection)
cf.createQueueConnection();

MQQueueSession session = (MQQueueSession) connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
MQQueue queue = (MQQueue) session.createQueue(queuename);
MQQueueSender sender = (MQQueueSender) session.createSender(queue);
TextMessage message = (TextMessage) session.createTextMessage("Hello");

// Start the connection
connection.start();
sender.send(message);

sender.close();
session.close();
connection.close();
```

MQSenderInternal

```
MQQueueConnectionFactory cf = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
cf.setHostName(host);
cf.setPort(port);
cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
cf.setQueueManager(manager);
cf.setChannel(channel);

MQQueueConnection connection = (MQQueueConnection)
cf.createQueueConnection();

MQQueueSession session = (MQQueueSession) connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
MQQueue queue = (MQQueue) session.createQueue(queuename);
MQQueueSender sender = (MQQueueSender) session.createSender(queue);
TextMessage message = (TextMessage) session.createTextMessage("Loop");

// Start the connection
connection.start();
sender.send(message);

sender.close();
session.close();
connection.close();
```

MQListener

```
public void onMessage(Message rcvMessage) {
    TextMessage msg = null;
    try {
        if (rcvMessage instanceof TextMessage) {
            msg = (TextMessage) rcvMessage;

            if (msg.getText().equals("Loop")) {
                System.out.println("Received Message from internal sender: "
                        + msg.getText());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Received Message from standalone sender: "
                        + msg.getText());

                MQSenderInternal.send();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Message of wrong type: "
                    + rcvMessage.getClass().getName());
        }
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); ;
        mdbContext.setRollbackOnly();
    }
}
```

Please any help is appreciated :)

Comment: What is the runtime exception which was thrown?

Comment: @TimMcCormick NoClassDefFound for com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory... which is pretty odd because the jars are included

Comment: That's the kind of problem you'll see if you bundle the JAR files with your application, which IBM don't support. The correct approach is to install the MQ JCA resource adapter in JBoss. Is that what you did?

Comment: @TimMcCormick Sorry for the late answer, but yes it was a jar dependency issue, thanks for the clue!